# How to find the light source position?

Tags: plotting

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, 
AxesOrigin -> {1, 1, -1}, 
Lighting -> {{"Directional", Gray, 
ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, ViewPoint -> {-1, 1, -2.7}, 
ViewAngle -> 35 Degree, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

I am practicing how to use lighting function to make object looked best.In above script, I cannot understand `ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]`,I read the official explanation, `Directional` should be from `pt1` to `pt2`,but I cannot find them in `ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]`.
Where is the light source in above plot?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcYZF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: "`ImageScaled` gives the position of a graphical object in terms of coordinates scaled to run from 0 to 1 across the whole image region in each direction."  [**»**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageScaled.html)

So it's scaled relative to the coordinate system of your plot. I think this will help explain it:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[Sphere[], ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
   Lighting -> {{"Directional", Gray, ImageScaled[{x, y, z}]}}
  ],
 {{x, 2}, -5, 5},
 {{y, 2}, -5, 5},
 {{z, 2}, 0, 5}
 ]
```

Comment: ImageScaled should be `0 -1`, why you set `-5,5`?

Comment: Larger than one or less than zero just means scale outside of the plot range